# Why did the Community Bot reshuffle the CV meta?

Tags: discussion

Two days ago the Community bot pushed a great amount of old threads. I've somewhat lost track of the more recent ones that I found interesting and when I went online the other day I was a little confused as to what happened. Was this a one-time event or will the bot continue to more actively push up old questions? Interestingly it seemed to have pushed questions with accepted answers as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were many posts over the years that contained links to Meta Stack Overflow, which served as both the meta for SO and as the meta for the Stack Exchange system.  But recently (see the official announcement [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/)), meta.SO has been changed / split into [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (the meta for the whole SE system) and [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) proper (which is now the meta only for SO).  Most of the old meta.SO threads are now meta.SE threads.  As a result, the links in our old meta.CV posts needed to be updated.  The community bot edited all those posts to update the links.  The reshuffling was just a side effect.